# cups unix domain socket localhost (socat)

Tags: cups-lpd

I tried to run cups service using uds (unix domain socket) via tcp port forwarder (socat) after commenting Listen 631 into /etc/cups/cupsd.conf and restarted the cups server. I also ran this command:

$ sudo socat TCP:localhost:631,fork,reuseaddr UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/cups/cups.sock

I got:

2023/03/25 11:34:40 socat[344011] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:631, 16): Connection refused

How can i make above command work?

Below command works, but the problem it is listening on 0.0.0.0 and its accesible outside my computer, security issue...

$ sudo socat tcp4-listen:631,fork,reuseaddr unix-connect:/var/run/cups/cups.sock

Answer (score 0):

this command worked for me:

$ sudo socat UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/cups/cups.sock TCP4-LISTEN:631,bind=localhost,fork,reuseaddr &

I opened the browser and typed url: localhost:631 hit enter and cups web interface started/forward unix domain socket communication.

The only thing is still not working is logging cups service web interface to change configuration, add printer, etc ...

Any idea?

Thx